# How do I add a value to the $values array in Woocommerce?

Tags: arrays, woocommerce

I'm trying to get my own custo`m value in the $values array, but I'm having some trouble to find out where the array is actually build.

I think I need to edit class-wc-cart.php, but if I just add my variable to

```
$this->cart_contents[$cart_item_key] = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item', array_merge( $cart_item_data, array(
                'product_id'    => $product_id,
                'variation_id'  => $variation_id,
                'variation'     => $variation,
                'quantity'      => $quantity,
                'data'          => $product_data
            ) ), $cart_item_key );
```

I get an error. So I was wondering where the $values array is actually build.